# Is there any small kernel good enough for learning osdev?

Tags: kernel, osdev, kernel-mode

I would like to learn more about osdev. So I thought about learning from other small kernels to get better at osdev. Is there any good kernel for learning osdev? Of course it needs to be GPL so I can have access to source code and have the freedom to modify it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. [FreeRTOS](http://www.freertos.org/index.html) is as small as it can get. The kernel image is just 4K-9K! It is an RTOS but it will give you a fair idea about OSs in general too!
2. [Minix](http://www.minix3.org/) is another that many prefer! Though its not that small but its quite popular in education circles!
3. [FemtoOS](http://www.femtoos.org/index.html) might also interest you!
4. [TinyOS](http://www.tinyos.net/) also serves a similar purpose!

Most of what I've listed come from the embedded world. Because thats where size and simplicity matter!

Answer (score 8):

http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs140/projects/pintos/pintos.html

PintOS is another addition to the above. Very simple framework and implementation is extremely simple to understand. Popularly used to introduce students to OS design and implementation.

Comment: This is a really lightweight build. It's a shame I can't get it to run.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a kernel as such, but a tutorial for writing your own, so maybe you'll find it helpful:

[Roll your own toy UNIX-clone OS](http://johnvidler.co.uk/mirror/jamesm-kernel-tutorial/)

EDIT:
The above link is no longer valid. Try [this](http://www.jamesmolloy.co.uk/tutorial_html/index.html) instead.